# Can't parse decimal number (Input string was not in a correct format)

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse the following string to a decimal

```
var decimalString = "450.000000"
```

I have tried the following:

```
var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo{ NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };
var dec = decimal.Parse(decimalString, numberFormatInfo);
```

This did not work.
I have also tried:

```
var dec = decimal.Parse(decimalString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This also throws the same error

> Input string was not in a correct format

EDIT:
This is the exact code:

```
private NumberFormatInfo _numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };
public void SetQuantity(string quantity)
    {
        try
        {
            _quantity = decimal.Parse(quantity, _numberFormatInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.WriteEntry($"Holding - SetQuantity Exception: {ex.Message} Value: {quantity}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please copy paste the code that does not work. Both ways work at my machine after fixing the typos.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis this is the code that is not working for me it keeps giving me the error i have given.

Comment: You code works on my machine as well. Maybe there is something else which causes the problem. That's why C.Evenhuis posted that comment.

Comment: @RemigijusG. `NumberDecimalSeperator` and `InvarientCulture` contain typos, and you're not using the `numberFormatInfo` after creating it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can understand. You have compiler errors in the code. Make sure to copy a working (compiling) code

Comment: Sorry those are typos and will fix them now (its not copy paste of the code as the code is on another pc). If it helps i am using this in a Windows Service which i dont think should make any difference.

Comment: So this is an example, but in your real code the string to parse could be different i guess. In that case, first make sure what's in the string you are trying to parse, as `decimal.Parse` would parse `450.000000` without any exception

Comment: `InvarientCulture` still wrong, but other than that the main problem is: your code is working! Make sure you really have an error there.

Comment: code works after fixing few typos: 
1 line - missing ; 
InvarientCulture -> InvariantCulture.

No error message

Comment: The `TryParse` method could help you. Or a logging framework where you can log the values to have an idea what you're trying to parse when it's not working. Maybe debugging via "attach to process" as well; depending where your Visual Studio runs and where your service.

Comment: I have added the actual code we are using and the value that gets passed into the method is "450.000000"

Comment: I was wondering could it be failing because of the 0's at the end? But then i guess it would not work for any of you guys either.

Comment: What is your locale? As stated by many people above, that code doesn't fail

Comment: @grek40 I have posted the actual code i have used and it is not working i have called it directly and passed in "450.000000" it is also not working. My country and region on my PC is set to United Kingdom.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DFKso9 now it's your turn to get something thats not working.

Comment: Yes i understand that the code is working, but do you have any constructive comment or an answer why this might not be working on my machine as that is the question.

Comment: Actually, if you create a new C# project, copy-paste the fiddle code without any modification, run the code and the error occurs, I recommend you create a new question (this one is kindof burned). Then it's important to mention all the details about the exact versions of Visual Studio, .Net Framework etc. Make sure to point out in the question that you have the exact code working in one place and the same code not working on your machine.

Comment: Thanks i guess i will have to create a new question. i have tried my code on my colleagues pc and it work so it is very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little bit of testing; perhaps it gives you a pointer as to where to look for the issue…

The following minimal working example will print the error message:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

static class DecimalTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dec = 0M;
        var decStr = "450.000000";
        var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };
        var parsed = decimal.TryParse(decStr, default(NumberStyles),
                                      nfi, out dec);
        if (parsed)
            Console.WriteLine("Decimal value: {0}", dec);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Sheet happened!");
    }
}
```

After replacing `default(NumberStyles)` by `NumberStyles.Any`, the number is parsed correctly.

Comment: `default(NumberStyles)` results in `NumberStyles.None`, which has the comment: _Indicates that no style elements, such as leading or trailing white space, thousands separators, or a __decimal separator__, can be present in the parsed string. The string to be parsed must consist of integral decimal digits only._ This all seems to work as expected.

Comment: I have tried setting the NumberStyles too and that seems to have fixed the problem. Really odd, but atleast it works now. Thanks for your help.